# Не присваиваются поля в Calendar.setup

Tags: javascript, html

Есть календарь. Не могу присвоить параметры в календаре - выводит `alert` что не присвоены параметры, то есть получается, что `setup` вызывается, но не присваиваются поля:

> Calendar.setup:\n  Nothing to setup (no fields found).  Please check your cod)

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/calendar/lang/calendar-en.js">&#160;</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Calendar.setup(
    {
        inputField: "dtFrom",
        button: "btnFrom"
    });
    Calendar.setup(
    {
        inputField: "dtTo",
        button: "btnTo"
    });
</script>
```

JS самого календаря:

```
Calendar.setup = function (params) {
    function param_default(pname, def) {
        if (typeof params[pname] == "undefined") {
            params[pname] = def;
        }
    };

    param_default("inputField", null);
    param_default("displayArea", null);
    param_default("button", null);
    param_default("eventName", "click");
    param_default("ifFormat", "%d/%m/%Y");
    param_default("daFormat", "%d/%m/%Y");
    param_default("singleClick", true);
    param_default("disableFunc", null);
    param_default("dateStatusFunc", params["disableFunc"]); // takes precedence if both are defined
    param_default("dateText", null);
    param_default("firstDay", 1);
    param_default("align", "Br");
    param_default("range", [1995, 2010]);
    param_default("weekNumbers", false);
    param_default("flat", null);
    param_default("flatCallback", null);
    param_default("onSelect", null);
    param_default("onClose", null);
    param_default("onUpdate", null);
    param_default("date", null);
    param_default("showsTime", false);
    param_default("timeFormat", "24");
    param_default("electric", true);
    param_default("step", 2);
    param_default("position", null);
    param_default("cache", false);
    param_default("showOthers", false);
    param_default("multiple", null);

    var tmp = ["inputField", "displayArea", "button"];
    for (var i in tmp) {
        if (typeof params[tmp[i]] == "string") {
            params[tmp[i]] = document.getElementById(params[tmp[i]]);
        }
    }
    if (!(params.flat || params.multiple || params.inputField || params.displayArea || params.button)) {
        alert("Calendar.setup:\n  Nothing to setup (no fields found).  Please check your code");
        return false;
    }

    function onSelect(cal) {
        var p = cal.params;
        var update = (cal.dateClicked || p.electric);
        if (update && p.inputField) {
            p.inputField.value = cal.date.print(p.ifFormat);
            if (typeof p.inputField.onchange == "function") p.inputField.onchange();
        }
        if (update && p.displayArea) p.displayArea.innerHTML = cal.date.print(p.daFormat);
        if (update && typeof p.onUpdate == "function") p.onUpdate(cal);
        if (update && p.flat) {
            if (typeof p.flatCallback == "function") p.flatCallback(cal);
        }
        if (update && p.singleClick && cal.dateClicked) cal.callCloseHandler();
    };

    if (params.flat != null) {
        if (typeof params.flat == "string") params.flat = document.getElementById(params.flat);
        if (!params.flat) {
            alert("Calendar.setup:\n  Flat specified but can't find parent.");
            return false;
        }
        var cal = new Calendar(params.firstDay, params.date, params.onSelect || onSelect);
        cal.showsOtherMonths = params.showOthers;
        cal.showsTime = params.showsTime;
        cal.time24 = (params.timeFormat == "24");
        cal.params = params;
        cal.weekNumbers = params.weekNumbers;
        cal.setRange(params.range[0], params.range[1]);
        cal.setDateStatusHandler(params.dateStatusFunc);
        cal.getDateText = params.dateText;
        if (params.ifFormat) {
            cal.setDateFormat(params.ifFormat);
        }
        if (params.inputField && typeof params.inputField.value == "string") {
            cal.parseDate(params.inputField.value);
        }
        cal.create(params.flat);
        cal.show();
        return false;
    }

    var triggerEl = params.button || params.displayArea || params.inputField;
    triggerEl["on" + params.eventName] = function () {
        var dateEl = params.inputField || params.displayArea;
        var dateFmt = params.inputField ? params.ifFormat : params.daFormat;
        var mustCreate = false;
        var cal = window.calendar;
        if (dateEl) params.date = Date.parseDate(dateEl.value || dateEl.innerHTML, dateFmt);
        if (!(cal && params.cache)) {
            window.calendar = cal = new Calendar(params.firstDay,
            params.date,
            params.onSelect || onSelect,
            params.onClose || function (cal) {
                cal.hide();
            });
            cal.showsTime = params.showsTime;
            cal.time24 = (params.timeFormat == "24");
            cal.weekNumbers = params.weekNumbers;
            mustCreate = true;
        } else {
            if (params.date) cal.setDate(params.date);
            cal.hide();
        }
        if (params.multiple) {
            cal.multiple = {};
            for (var i = params.multiple.length; --i >= 0;) {
                var d = params.multiple[i];
                var ds = d.print("%Y%m%d");
                cal.multiple[ds] = d;
            }
        }
        cal.showsOtherMonths = params.showOthers;
        cal.yearStep = params.step;
        cal.setRange(params.range[0], params.range[1]);
        cal.params = params;
        cal.setDateStatusHandler(params.dateStatusFunc);
        cal.getDateText = params.dateText;
        cal.setDateFormat(dateFmt);
        if (mustCreate) cal.create();
        cal.refresh();
        if (!params.position) cal.showAtElement(params.button || params.displayArea || params.inputField, params.align);
        else cal.showAt(params.position[0], params.position[1]);
        return false;
    };

    return cal;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!(params.flat || params.multiple || params.inputField || params.displayArea || params.button)) {
    alert("Calendar.setup:\n  Nothing to setup (no fields found).  Please check your code");
    return false;
}
```

Проверяет твои параметры, inputField: "dtFrom", button: "btnFrom" заданы а остальные нет, поэтому условие в if приравнивается к true и получаеш свою ошибку.
if(!false) 
Попробуй задать все параметры котрые проверяются в этом if (params.flat || params.multiple || params.inputField || params.displayArea || params.button)